# getting TypeScript errors complaining on actually already transpiled JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemon

I'm trying to adapt existing tech stack (node, babel, webpack, react, server-side rendering, react-hot-loader, etc) to TypeScript. I've been able to use `tsc` with `allowJs=true` and `awsome-typescript-loader` and all the ts/txj/js code compiles successfully. There is also `nodemon` being used for watching and reloading (with output `build` dir ignored) and here I hit the problem - I'm getting errors like:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/universal/components/Page1Container/Page1Container.tsx:3:30
    TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

which are caused by `tsc` trying to compile already compiled output JS (the line/column number are matching possible `tsc` problem in output JS) and what's weird is that the error comes from `awsome-typescript-loader` and shows source `tsx` file which is not correct. From the logs it looks like there is a webpack bundling when the errors shows up. Also in `tsconfig.json` the output `build` dir is excluded. I've got stuck here and not sure where to look for the reason/solution.

`tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "docs",
    "tests",
    "tools",
    "gulpfile.js",
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useCache": true,
    "useBabel": true
  }
}
```

as for `webpack` config for each `module.rule` having `awsome-typescript-loader` there is `build` output exclusion (may need to verify whether it works actually).

Comment: Would you post the code?

Comment: Just Page1Container.tsx should be enough. My guess is that you are consuming an object that is not initialized at load but initialized by something else later on like a method. So typescript is saying that it could be undefined. Seeing the code would help.

Comment: Can you post  your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I'm thinking about isolating it as now it's pretty complex environment being result of custom yeoman generator combining lot of other custom components.

Comment: @Juan yet the message does not makes sense - some line numbers are out of tsx lines and I'm sure the complains is for the JS output of already transpiled tsx. And all the configuration is not expected to build the JS output once more (the output build is being excluded hopefully everywhere)